# Em in fingerstyling, is it different?

Tags: chords, fingerstyle-guitar

I am fairly new to guitar, and I've been learning the basic chords for a month and so now, and I came across this yesterday, when trying to learn a song. [image]

It says it starts with an E minor, but that doesn't look like an E minor. Are chords different in finger styling?

Answer (score 2):

That’s an Em chord. Any chord that has the notes E, G, B is an E minor chord, and if E is the lowest note, its chord symbol is ”Em”. (If, say, G was the lowest note, it would be a so-called *inversion* and the chord symbol would be ”Em/G”.)

The sounding notes at the start are E, G, B and G as the high melody note.

- E string open (0) : E (lowest note, bass note)
- A string : not played, no note
- D string : not played, no note
- G string open (0) : G
- B string open (0) : B
- E string 3rd fret : G (melody note)

E + G + B is a basic E minor chord.

After that the melody goes down from G to F#, E.

Comment: I am kind of confused, doesn't E minor only use 2 fingers? A string and B string on the second fret? Like this one: https://imgur.com/a/F7teufy

Comment: @user65342 I edited the answer. Any chord that has the notes E, G, B and E as the lowest note, is an E minor.

Comment: @piiperiReinstateMonica - in Em, the E doesn't *have* to be the lowest note. There are three options for the lowest note; when E is at the bottom it's called root position, then there are two inversions. But all three chords, whatever is at the bottom, are still E minor

Answer (score 2):

Most times, yes, Em open *is* played with just the two notes fretted on the A and D strings, 2nd fret.

However - E minor is made up from just three notes - E G and B. They *could* be played as a three string chord on guitar, or, could be doubled up or even tripled - which is what happens to the E notes in the chord you know. But - by losing the top E and replacing it with a top G? Well, we still have the same three notes, just a different mix! It's called a different *voicing*, and is quite permissable and correct - just not the one shown in most books to beginners!

An excercise I use with students is to consider the notes making up a chord, and find each one on a convenient string. When all 5 or 6 are accomodated, look at the shape. It's probably one that's very familiar! Have a try with some triads - GBD is a nice one. It'll help you understand *why* chord shapes are like they are on guitar.

Comment: Thank you, this was very helpful. One more question though, if E minor is made up from E G and B, how is it that holding A and D on the second fret and strumming all the strings considered an E minor?

Also, Is it better to start learning early what notes make up chords if I am into finger styling?

Comment: We're not holding A and D - we're holding the A and D strings on 2nd fret, which in turn produce notes B and E. Like I suggested, try spelling a chord, note by note, and find those notes on different strings, close enough to be all played together - you've made a chord! (NOT the A and B strings in your comment!).

Comment: Oh, I get it now!!, I tried spelling a G chord, which turned out to be G B and G, and an A Major is C# A and E. Hopefully that's correct! thank you so much, this helped me a lot

Comment: What you've just achieved is far more valuable than you maybe realise! And where did D disappear to in G major?

Comment: Isn't the G chord supposed to be played like that? Lowest E 3rd fret, A 2nd fret and Highest E 3rd fret, which comes to G B and G?

Comment: Do what I suggest - find *either* a G a B or a D on *each* string. Some are already there, open, but you'll find there's an option on the B string. What you're missing is the fact that any *open* strings sound as well - with their own name. True, you're not fretting them, but sure as heck you're playing them!

Comment: Sorry, kind of confused now, please take a look at this: https://imgur.com/a/tsDBSmg
That's a G major, Lowest E 3rd fret, A 2nd fret, and Highest E 3rd fret = G B and G

Isn't that correct? E on the third fret becomes a G, doesn't it?

am I missing something? Is there supposed to be a D? I know I am strumming the open D along with the chord, but not sure if that's it

Comment: You haven't done as I suggested have you? Thick to thin, the 6 notes are - G B D G B G. The 'missing' D is the open D string (4th string open).

Comment: Yeah, I understand that and I've tried what you suggested, however, why does my chord book show a G major having notes G B D when the notes shown on the fretboard diagram are G B G ? Another example is the C chord, which shows as  C E G, but on the fretboard diagram it's C E C.

Sorry, I am just totally confused

Comment: All you are homing in on are the notes you are *pressing down*. You must also consider the notes that are *open string notes*. Surely you must realise that they are also part of the chord - otherwise why would you strum them and why wouldn't they sound right?

Comment: Yeah, I get it now, and I realized that the other notes are doubled as well in some of the basic chords I've seen (the same note twice but a higher pitch?) in G B D G B G. There are 3 G's, 2 B's. Does this happen for every chord as well? And, I assume that if you change one of the G's to a C, it wouldn't be a G chord anymore?

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you're confusing chord-shapes with chords.

There may be a hundred way to play Em on the guitar. What they all have in common is the notes E,G and B. The notes may be this way up or that; they may be arpegiated or simultaneous; they may all be present or just two of them; they may be doubled or trebled. It makes no difference. In all case it is the same chord.

A chord is a fixed and definite set of notes. A chord-shape is one of many and various ways of playing those notes.

Answer (score 1):

That's an E minor chord at the start. I don't think the contents of chords are any different in fingerstyling (though the most often used voicings very well could be).

The played notes at the very start, from bottom to top, are E-G-B-G: a match for an E minor chord. The next two notes you need to play are F♯ and E. (Treat the F♯ as a passing note.)

Comment: I am kind of confused, doesn't E minor only use 2 fingers? A string and B string on the second fret? Like this one: imgur.com/a/F7teufy

Comment: @user65342 - The chord in the imgur picture you linked to is also an E minor chord as long as you play all the strings. There is more than one way to voice an E minor chord.

Answer (score 1):

An E min chord is just the notes (E, G, B) with possible repeated notes.  There must be a dozen ways to play this, and every other chord out there, on the guitar.  So, when judging what a chord is try to use the formula.  Use the major scale degrees.

Major scale degrees = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7) or (1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13).

Major chord = (1, 3, 5)

Minor chord = (1, b3, 5)

Diminished  = (1, b3, b5)

Augmented = (1, 3, #5)

Maj 7th chord = (1, 3, 5, 7)

Dominant 7 = (1, 3, 5, b7)

Minor 7th = (1, b3, 5, b7)

etc, etc.